# webview opening .mht file inside file explorer

Tags: java, android

i use this to open saved offline .mht page files in my web browser

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="multipart/related" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-bittorrent" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.torrent" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mhtml" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mht" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mhtml" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.mht" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but the problem is if i open the file from like ES File Explorer my web browser is opened inside the File Explorer with the page shown.

if i open the file from the File Explorer with UC Web browser it is opened separetly.

what to do when opening .mht file from File Explorer to be opened separetly.

here is what it looks like

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM1b2.jpg)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKXA0.jpg)

Comment: `my web browser is opened inside the File Explorer with the page shown.` That is not your webbrowser or webview. That is a webview of ES File Explorer.

Comment: what is wrong with u! i have made my own browser.cant u read!

Comment: Yes i know that you made your own browser. But it looks that es file explorer uses its own webview. Not yours. That is what i said. You could have elaborated on that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `android:launchMode` in manifest for your activity to "singleTask" or "singleInstance" (The default mode is "standard").

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
    ...
   </activity>
```

Please see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=ru#lmode

and https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack